# 複数の行列の掛け算を同時に行う

Tags: python, 画像, numpy, pytorch

Python
numpyかpytorchで複数の行列の掛け算をforループを用いずに同時に行いたいです。

例えば10×100の異なる行列が5個と100×100の行列が一つあるとします。

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,10,100)
b = np.random.rand(100,100)
```

aが10×100の異なる5個の行列でbが100×100の行列です。

```
c= np.zeros((5,10,100))
for i in range(len(a)):
    c[i] = np.dot(a[i],b)
```

もしくはpytorchで

```
import torch
c = torch.zeros((5,10,100))
a = torch.randn(5,10,100)
b = torch.randn(100,100)
for i in range(len(a)):
    c[i] = torch.mm(a[i],b)
```

何か案があれば教えていただけると幸いです。

このようにfor文でなら実現できますがaの個数が5から増えると遅くなってしまいます。
行列bは同じものなので並行して行列の掛け算を行いたいです。

Comment: 試しに私の環境でnumpy(anaconda)にて実行してみたらaの個数を100にした場合でもforループ以降が566マイクロ秒で終了します。わかるなら実行時間を提示できますか。

Comment: すみません、実際につかう行列は40000×40000くらいで計算時間が問題になるかと思っていたのですが、GPUを使ったところ0.01秒ほどで実行できました。

Answer (score 1):

実際につかう行列は40000×40000くらいで計算時間が問題になるかと思っていたのですが、GPUを使って計算したところ0.01秒ほどで実行できました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @potiki さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49054/#comment50997_49054)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>